# How to make a progressbar with time data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a progressbar and the value will be a time between the beginning and the end of an action. like exemple ( i start at 1pm to 3pm ) i want to make something like, see the progression between the two hours.

I started with a simple progresse bar with random value :

```
import React from 'react';
import './ProgressBar.css'

const ProgressBar = ({width, progressColor}) => (
  <div>
    <div className="meter" style={{background: progressColor}}>
      <span style={{width: width +'%', background: progressColor}} className="progress"/>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default ProgressBar
```

and

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './index.css';
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";
import Clock from 'react-live-clock';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 20,
      clock: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="">
          <ProgressBar width={this.state.width} progressColor={"#1725b5"}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And now i am looking for values ​​over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Have `ProgressBar` be a dumb component. It only needs to know about what progress to render
2. Have `App` be a smart component which knows `start` and `end` values and keeps track of `progress` based on the current time (it calculates what value to provide to the `ProgressBar`)

I've used minutes instead of hours here so that it is easier to demonstrate. Update the `start`, `end` and `getProgress` to suit your requirements.

```js
const ProgressBar = ({status, progressColor}) => (
  <div style={{background: '#fff', border: '1px solid #000', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <div style={{transform: `scaleX(${status})`, transformOrigin: '0 0', transition: 'transform 1s', height: 10, background: progressColor}} />
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: this.getProgress(),
    }
  }
  
  getProgress() {
    const {start, end} = this.props;
    const now = new Date().valueOf();
    return (now - start) / (end - start);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const progress = this.getProgress();
      if (progress > 1) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      this.setState({
        progress
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ProgressBar status={this.state.progress} progressColor={"#1725b5"}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const now = new Date().valueOf();
const start = Math.floor(now / 60000) * 60000; // current minute
const end = start + 60000; // start + 1 minute
ReactDOM.render(
  <App start={start} end={end} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Comment: Great to hear. Please accept the answer if it does what you expect it to do.

Comment: I did it, but just a question about the « math.floor », why us it?

Comment: I used it to get to the beginning of the minute. So, I divide by the number of milliseconds and floor it be removing decimals and multiply it by the number of milliseconds in a minute again

Answer (score 1):

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```